# How to use Guice Injector to avoid declaring string as static

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, inject

I'm actually new to using Guice injector. I have a situation where I have a String variable in one class and I want to use this variable in a different class without declaring it as static .  Can I know how to use Guice injector here to avoid declaring it static

```
public class A {

  private string a;
  public void Method() {
  a = "abc";
  }
}

public class B {
  public void method2() {
  String b = a;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the directly to the instance of a string using the `Names` annotation.

```
bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("PROPERTY")).toInstance("Some String");
```

Although a better way to do it would be to use `Properties`:

```
// Your choice of loading properties
Properties properties = getPropreties();
Names.bindProperties(binder(), properties);
```

Then you can use either of these with

```
@Inject @Named("my.property") String myProperty;
```